# iOS App Store - retiring an app - Can I hide the app from new users while making updates available to all existing users

Tags: ios, app-store, end-of-life

I have an app that needs to be retired, as it is no longer self-sustaining, due to server costs, etc. However, there are still active users of the app, who I don't want to burn on this shutdown (eg. suddenly shutting down and permanently cutting off access to their data)

To support a "polite" shutdown, I'll need to update the app to provide a means of exporting all their data (which is stored *partially* locally in the app, and *partially* on the server... so merely turning on iTunes File Sharing is not sufficient) to the server, where we can then email them a zip of all their content. This updated version and supporting server will be available for several months to give them a window to migrate everything out, before ultimately pulling the plug on everything in a few months. However, I don't want new users to install and start using the app during this time period (or at least minimize this as much as possible), as the app is effectively a "dead man walking".

So, my question is then: **is it possible to push out app updates to existing installs, while preventing new installs from the iOS App Store?**

I've already seen references to ways to "hide" an app from the app store (eg. setting its status to "Removed From Sale", setting its availability date into the future, or restricting its availability to only a single small country like St Lucia), but none of these makes clear if that restricts just *new downloads*, or if that also restricts the ability to download the *app update*... which is absolutely critical to my shutdown plan.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that.  As a less-optimal alternative, you could change the App Store description to explain that the app is going away, and maybe put out an update that detects a new user (no account on server, maybe?) and pops up a message explaining the situation when they run your app.  But as far as I know, any restrictions on downloading will also restrict updates.

Comment: I'll definitely be taking those steps as well, just trying to minimize how many people find themselves in that situation in our app... especially as their first experience. Was hoping maybe Apple had documented this somewhere, or someone had first-hand experience with how updates work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think App Store allows for this kind of behavior. What you can do? The simples way is to store flag in user defaults that represents if this app is already installed. If its not, you just show alert without possibility to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I realize I can restrict their access after they've installed it, but my hope is to prevent them from ever installing it _in the first place_, since installing a new app that is immediately useless is not exactly a good user experience, and would reflect poorly on the developer, me :)   And with other apps on the store under that same account, I'd also like to minimize the number of inevitable "this app doesn't even work" 1-star comments due to releasing a disabled app for new users.   Just trying to do my best to save face while winding this down.