# Can I offer an iOS app update, but prevent new user from downloading app?

Tags: ios, migration, app-store, app-store-connect

I need to push out an app-update, that sets the app (app-A) up for being migrated and retired. The new app that users will migrate to (app-B, different bundleId) is ready, so I would prefer it, if there are no new users to app-A.

Concretely: Can I offer app-updates to app-A, while preventing users from installing it new?

I have seen this not-encouraging post from 2017: [iOS App Store - retiring an app - Can I hide the app from new users while making updates available to all existing users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773167/ios-app-store-retiring-an-app-can-i-hide-the-app-from-new-users-while-making) - it's been a while, so things are looking better presently.

Creativity is allright here, but obviously any updates to app-A needs to pass review, so it can't just be an empty shell that points to app-B.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Sorry, no... It looks like I have to be okay with the user downloading the retiring app (A). I have made sure to tell the user about the situation, to encourage using (B) instead, obviously including good links to appstore, and deeplinks into B, so that everything is as painless as possible.

Comment: I was going to suggest to push your update for app (a), then take it down and launch app(b) at the same time. That way app (a) is updated but new users can only download app (b).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post :)

While this would appear to solve the problem - from what I understand, user will no longer be able to update app A, if it is removed from app store. Some users may have auto-updated, or may have been quick to update manually, but someone will be left behind. The update of A is crucial for getting the migration code onto devices, so data can be transferred to B.

Comment: You could send out a notification to all current user stating the last update will be on (given date) and to download the new app after it is released. You could set the notification to grout to new users as well.

Comment: That will certainly rescue a bigger group of users. On the other hand, some will have notifications turned of, and some will ignore the notification. It is very important to my client, that users will not lose data (unless deleting the app...), so it looks' like I need to keep A afloat until I'm 100% sure everybody got the update - although that means new users on A. 

They will be told about B, but it would be nice to spare them the install of A :/

Comment: Hmm good points, and that is a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

After being in contact with Apple support about this, it is clear that it is not possible. The following is copied verbatim from Apple support reply:

> Currently, there is no feature that could allow you to prevent potencial users to download the app, while it is still available in the App Store. To prevent users from downloading app, you will need to remove it from the App Store.

The "solution" is to keep the A app around - and only providing the move-to-B functionality - until we either see no activity on it, or don't care anymore.